# What is the significance of the number of stars of a github repository?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, github, open-source

You can favorite a gem or something on github, but what does this number signify? E.g. the [AngularJS Rails gem](https://github.com/hiravgandhi/angularjs-rails) has 750 stars, and I wasn't sure how to interpret that. Does this mean there's only 750 developers interested in this, or ever used it? Basically why would someone be interested in receiving notifications from this public repository?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/about-stars/

Comment: I guess I wanted to ask this question from a developer's world point of view, not just the definition according to the glossary.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that people have starred it. As far as why people have starred it, well that's a difficult thing to measure. I usually star repositories that I find interesting or want to revisit but do not need or want to fork. This isn't a question that will fetch a cut and dry answer, but I would argue that it is a measure of interest in the repo. You don't need to use it to star it and vice versa.